# pdfjs: Fill out a form and get the fieldValues

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I'm using *pdfjs* to display a PDF form (acroforms example). If I fill in some fields, how do I get those annotations.

I've tried:

```
pdfPage.getAnnotations().then(function(a) {
for(var i = 0;i < a.length; i++) {
  console.log(a[i].id + ' - ' + a[i].fieldValue);
  } 
});
```

But all I get are empty *fieldValues*. I guess I'm getting them from the original PDF. How do I access the *live* document which includes the new annotations?

Comment: You should understand that acrosform example add an html layer with an html form to the rendered pdf ; so, you should care to save edited values using html events and then produce a xfdf file that is fully supported by acrobat ; please remove negative comment below so I can improve answer with example (even if you may find everything in the proposed link)

Answer (score 3):

```
    async getAnnotations() {
    var result = {};                
    var pages = PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.numPages;
    for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
        var page = await PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.getPage(i);
        var annotations = await page.getAnnotations();
        for (var j = 0; j < annotations.length; j++) {
            var element = annotations[j];
            // Field Name
            if (result[element.fieldName] == null) {
                result[element.fieldName] = null;
            }
        
                var val = PDFViewerApplication.pdfDocument.annotationStorage.getOrCreateValue(element.id);
                if (element.radioButton) {
                    if (val.value) {
                        result[element.fieldName] = element.buttonValue;
                    }
                } else if (element.checkBox) {
                    result[element.fieldName] = val.value ? "On" : "Off";
                } else {
                    result[element.fieldName] = val.value;
                }                                
        }             
    };              

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should save values written by user in a local variable

Then you should create a xfdf file ( xml file by Adobe ) , look for Example nere : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Adobe_XFDF . The xfdf should then be merged with original pdf to produce a new compiled pdf